# How to put an email address in url on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, url

I want to invite people who passes their email inside an url like this:

```
localhost:3000/invite_me/email@gmail.com
```

I tried this `match` but it isn't working.

```
match "/invite_me/:email" => "application#invite_me",
    :constraints => { :email => '/.+@.+\..*/' }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/invite_me/waldyr.ar@gmail.com"
```

rake routes output:

```
root  /                           application#index
  /invite_me/:email(.:format) application#invite_me {:email=>"/.+@.+\\..*/"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your constraint needs to be an actual regular expression and not a string

```
match "/invite_me/:email" => "application#invite_me",
    :constraints => { :email => '/.+@.+\..*/' }
```

Should be

```
match "/invite_me/:email" => "application#invite_me",
    :constraints => { :email => /.+@.+\..*/ }
```